# PySpark Throwing error Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, flatmap

I have a set of files. The path to the files are saved in a file., say `all_files.txt`. Using apache spark, I need to do an operation on all the files and club the results.

The steps that I want to do are:

- Create an RDD by reading `all_files.txt`
- For each line in `all_files.txt` (Each line is a path to some file),
  read the contents of each of the files into a single RDD
- Then do an operation all contents

This is the code I wrote for the same:

```
def return_contents_from_file (file_name):
    return spark.read.text(file_name).rdd.map(lambda  r: r[0])

def run_spark():
    file_name = 'path_to_file'

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("PythonWordCount") \
        .getOrCreate()

    counts = spark.read.text(file_name).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]) \ # this line is supposed to return the paths to each file
        .flatMap(return_contents_from_file) \ # here i am expecting to club all the contents of all files
        .flatMap(do_operation_on_each_line_of_all_files) # here i am expecting do an operation on each line of all files
```

This is throwing the error:

> line 323, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error
>   occurred while calling o25.**getnewargs**. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Method **getnewargs**([]) does not exist  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)    at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `spark` inside `flatMap` or any transformation that occures on executors is not allowed (`spark` session is available on driver only). It is also not possible to create RDD of RDDs (see: [Is it possible to create nested RDDs in Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760722/is-it-possible-to-create-nested-rdds-in-apache-spark))

But you can achieve this transformation in another way - read all content of `all_files.txt` into dataframe, use **local** `map` to make them dataframes and **local** `reduce` to union all, see example:

```
>>> filenames = spark.read.text('all_files.txt').collect()
>>> dataframes = map(lambda r: spark.read.text(r[0]), filenames)
>>> all_lines_df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.unionAll(df2), dataframes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how do I parallelize the whole process?
wouldn't map(lambda r: spark.read.text(r[0]), filenames) serialize the whole process?

Comment: The process of reading files run in parallel, the only serialized part is building execution plan. Try it out!

Answer (score 6):

I meet this problem today, finally figure out that I refered to a `spark.DataFrame` object in `pandas_udf` , which result to this error .

The conclution:

You can't use `sparkSession` object , `spark.DataFrame` object or other Spark distributed objects in `udf` and `pandas_udf`, because they are unpickled.

If you meet this error and you are using `udf`, check it carefully , must be relative problem.

Comment: What's your solution then?

Comment: @Rock Only make sure no Spark distributed objects in `udf` and `pandas_udf `

Comment: Similarly, this error popped up for me when I accidentally returned a spark dataframe from a pandas_udf.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error trying to log my model with MLFlow using `mlflow.sklearn.log_model` when the model itself was a `pyspark.ml.classification` model. Using `mlflow.spark.log_model` solved the issue.