# Py4JException error while saving file to S3 with Glue

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue, py4j

I'm trying to save default value file to S3 bucket but getting below error:

```
An error occurred while calling o654.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code snippet I prepared, it seems to be `py4j` releated issue.
Thanks for suggestions!

```
    BUCKET = 'my_bucket'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    keyid = 'xxxxx'

    print("Uploading S3 object with SSE-KMS")
    s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET,
              Key='encrypt-key',
              Body=b'foobar',
              ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
              # Optional: SSEKMSKeyId
              SSEKMSKeyId=keyid)
    print("Saving to S3, Done")
```

Comment: Check if this issue is not similar to the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470487/pyspark-throwing-error-method-getnewargs-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential issue was wrong syntax for `Key`. It should follow `subfolder/subfolder/file_to_write.txt`.

`/` has to be added to each subfolder (aka key) name, otherwise AWS doesn't see it as a path in the bucket.