# Extract RDD[(Array[String]) from RDD[(String, Array[String]) [Spark/scala]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, extract, rdd

I have this prbolem, I have one of this kind  RDD[(String, Array[String]), and I would like extract from it a RDD[Array[String]] that contains the values grouped by key:

e.g:

```
val x :RDD[(String, Array[String]) = 
RDD[(a, Array[ "ra", "re", "ri"]),
(a, Array[ "ta", "te", "ti"]),
(b, Array[ "pa", "pe", "pi"])]
```

I would like get:

```
val result: RDD[(String, RDD[Array[String]]) = 
RDD[(a, RDD[Array[("ra", "re", "ri"),( "ta", "te", "ti")]]),
(b,  RDD[Array[("pa", "pe", "pi"),...]])
,...]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `reduceByKey` should solve your issue

```
x.reduceByKey((prev, next)=> (prev ++ next))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Spark doesn't support nested RDDs (see this [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42280790/6316508)).

In case nested arrays are good for what you need, a simple `groupByKey` will do:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", Array( "ra", "re", "ri" )),
  ("a", Array( "ta", "te", "ti" )),
  ("b", Array( "pa", "pe", "pi" ))
))

val x2 = x.groupByKey

x2.collect.foreach(println)
(a,CompactBuffer([Ljava.lang.String;@75043e31, [Ljava.lang.String;@18656538))
(b,CompactBuffer([Ljava.lang.String;@2cf30d2e))

x2.collect.foreach{ case (a, b) => println(a + ": " + b.map(_.mkString(" "))) }
a: List(ra re ri, ta te ti)
b: List(pa pe pi)
```